# How to access the Impala Parser

Tags: impala

Does Impala reuse hive SQL parser?

I am trying to write a custom Java code to check for query correctness in my application. I am searching for an api which can consume the sql query and let me know if it is grammatically correct for impala.

How can I access the parser from a custom Java code to check for query compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Impala does not reuse the Hive parser.
Further, Impala does not expose a Java API for checking if a query is grammatically correct.
The easiest thing to do is probably to submit an [explain query](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_explain_plan.html) via JDBC and check the result.

If you don't have a running Impala cluster, in theory you should be able to instantiate the  scanner and parser as Impala does in the [parser unit tests](https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/blob/aa0f6a2fc1d3fe21f22cc7bc56887e1fdb02250b/fe/src/test/java/com/cloudera/impala/analysis/ParserTest.java), but I can imagine it might be difficult to get that working as the Impala build/test environment is quite complicated. Note that this is not a supported API.

Comment: Thanks @matt.  But that would require me to have an impala system up and running.  Any suggestions if I can avoid that?

Comment: I edited the comment with a suggestion to avoid a running Impala cluster.

Answer (score 0):

To parse impala query by java api, you can refer to the following project [Impala-Query-Parser](https://github.com/tungtv289/Impala-Query-Parser)